# HTTP Get запрос c++

Tags: c++, http, get

на днях хотел сделать свой проект на WinApi(с GUI интерфейсом) который показывает текущую погоду.
Поискав я нашёл вот этот сайт(https://openweathermap.org/api),смотря примеры кода в интернете у меня выработалось мнение что нужно использовать asio или curl(libcurl).
Пробовал писать но получал в ответ какие-то такие ответы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как бы вы реализовали GET запрос на c++ c данного сайта?

P.S:
Либо теории не хватает либо я что-то неправильно делаю,но запросы у меня получаются в виде обрывков HTML кода.

```
Вот текущий код(если это вообще можно так назвать):

asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("openweathermap.org","http");
stream << "GET /ip HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=d98095230b8ae3366ae9\r\n\r\n";
cout << stream.rdbuf() << endl;
```

Comment: Например вместо Host указан url...

Comment: После get должен идти путь запроса с параметрами, а в хост указывается только адрес сайта, без пути.